# Resize Windows Terminal Programmatically in Python

Tags: python, windows, terminal

I'm working on implementing a simple splash screen before a program runs with a small animation, but I want to be able to resize the terminal to fit the full animation so the lines don't end up looping and messing it up. I'm doing this on Windows 11 with Python 3.10 and would like it done with python code, not manually typed into the terminal.

I've tried a number of solutions, the "\033c[8;{rows};{cols}t" escape code does not work on windows (but it does work on mac so the escape code isn't the issue, it's been reported at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094 and there didn't seem to be any solution). I've tried using the "mode" command with os.system() but when I scale the terminal size down with it, it only changes the area in which text can print, not the actual terminal window size, and also leaves some uninteracteable text that can't be cleared. I also tried using curses.resize_term() but couldn't get it functioning either, I'm not particularly versed in using curses so it's possible there was some mistake.

The program text is as follows:

````py
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from os import get_terminal_size
from sys import stdout

class SplashScreen:
    def __init__(self, splash: list[str], padding: list[int, int], terminal_size=[0, 0], speed=0.008, splash_time=1):
        self.splash = splash # The ascii splash screen
        self.padding = padding # The vertical and horizontal padding in newlines and spaces, respectively
        self.splash_time = splash_time # Wait time after animation (see SplashScreen.exec()) completion
        self.speed = speed # Speed of consecutive animation frames (see SplashScreen.exec())

        self.terminal_size = terminal_size # Sets self.terminal_size to min value to fit splash screen
        if self.terminal_size[0] < max([len(line) for line in self.splash])+2*padding[0]:
            self.terminal_size[0] = max([len(line) for line in self.splash])+2*padding[0]
        if self.terminal_size[1] < len(self.splash)+2*self.padding[1]:
            self.terminal_size[1] = len(self.splash)+2*self.padding[1]
        self.prev_terminal_size = ()
        self.cleaned = True # Bool used externally to check if splash screen animation is complete and reset

    def exec(self):
        self.cleaned = False # Show that terminal has not been reset
        self.prev_terminal_size = (get_terminal_size().columns, get_terminal_size().lines) # Save current terminal size for later restoration
        print(f"\x1b[8;{self.terminal_size[1]};{self.terminal_size[0]}t") # Escape sequence to change terminal size
        for i in range(max([len(line) for line in self.splash])): # Iterate through every column of characters in the splash screen
            screen = "\033c"+'\n'*self.padding[1] # Clear the screen and adds vertical space on top
            for line in self.splash: # Adds all the lines, showing up to i characters
                screen += self.padding[0]*" "+line[:i+1]+'\n'
            if i != 0 and perf_counter()-last_write < self.speed: # Checks whether the delay from the last print is great enough to reduce the sleep counter for iterating
                sleep(self.speed-(perf_counter()-last_write))
            last_write = perf_counter()
            stdout.write(screen) # Writes the current frame
            stdout.flush()
        sleep(self.splash_time) # Delay after animation completes
    
    def clean_up(self): # Resets terminal, for external calling
        self.cleaned = True
        print(f"\033c\x1b[8;{self.prev_terminal_size[1]};{self.prev_terminal_size[0]}t", end="") # Clears terminal and resets size with escape sequences

if __name__ == "__main__":
    splash_text = [
        r"      *******                                                                                                                       ",
        r"    *       ***                            *                    *                               *                                   ",
        r"   *         **                           ***                  **                              ***                                  ",
        r"   **        *                             *                   **                               *                                   ",
        r"    ***                     ***  ****               ****     ********    ****    ***  ****            **   ****                     ",
        r"   ** ***           ****     **** **** * ***       * ***  * ********    * ***  *  **** **** * ***      **    ***  * *** **** ****   ",
        r"    *** ***        * ***  *   **   ****   ***     *   ****     **      *   ****    **   ****   ***     **     ****   *** **** ***  *",
        r"      *** ***     *   ****    **           **    **    **      **     **    **     **           **     **      **     **  **** **** ",
        r"        *** ***  **           **           **    **    **      **     **    **     **           **     **      **     **   **   **  ",
        r"          ** *** **           **           **    **    **      **     **    **     **           **     **      **     **   **   **  ",
        r"           ** ** **           **           **    **    **      **     **    **     **           **     **      **     **   **   **  ",
        r"            * *  **           **           **    **    **      **     **    **     **           **     **      **     **   **   **  ",
        r"  ***        *   ***     *    ***          **    *******       **      ******      ***          **      ******* **    **   **   **  ",
        r" *  *********     *******      ***         *** * ******         **      ****        ***         *** *    *****   **   ***  ***  *** ",
        r"*     *****        *****                    ***  **                                              ***                   ***  ***  ***",
        r"*                                                **                                                                                 ",
        r" **                                              **                                                                                 ",
        r"                                                  **                                                                                "
    ]
    splash = SplashScreen(splash_text, padding=(6, 4))
    splash.exec()```
````